# Showing Uncaught TypeError: e.target.setCapture is not a function in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I get this error in chrome while calling init() on body onload but it is working fine in mozilla firefox

`Uncaught TypeError: e.target.setCapture is not a function`

If chrome is not supporting setCapture() then what can we do?

```
 function init() {
          var btn = document.getElementById("anchorId");
          btn.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown, false);
          btn.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp, false);
        }

        function mouseDown(e) {
         e.target.setCapture();
         e.target.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoved, false);
        }

        function mouseUp(e) {
          e.target.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoved, false);
        }

        function mouseMoved(e) {
                var x = e.clientX;     
                var y = e.clientY;     

                var anchorPathWidth = document.getElementById('anchorPath').offsetWidth;

                document.getElementById('anchorId').style.position = "absolute";
                document.getElementById('anchorId').style.left = (x * 100)/anchorPathWidth + "%";

        }
```

Comment: ok I'm looking for an alternative of setCapture() for chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this update:

```
function init() {
        alert(1);
      var btn = document.getElementById("anchorId");
      btn.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown, true);
      btn.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp, true);
    }

    function mouseDown(e) {
     console.log("Mouse Down");
     console.log(e.target)
     if(e.target.addEventListener)
     {
     e.target.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoved, true);
     }
        else
        {
            if(e.target.setCapture)
            {
             e.target.setCapture();
            }
        }
    }

    function mouseUp(e) {
      e.target.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoved, true);
      console.log("Mouse Up");
    }

    function mouseMoved(e) {
            var x = e.clientX;     // Get the horizontal coordinate
            var y = e.clientY;     // Get the vertical coordinate
            var coor = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
            console.log("Move the Div to " + coor);

            var anchorPathWidth = document.getElementById('anchorPath').offsetWidth;

            document.getElementById('anchorId').style.position = "absolute";
            document.getElementById('anchorId').style.left = (x * 100)/anchorPathWidth + "%";
            //console.log( x/anchorPathWidth + "%");    
    }
```

Live Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/nadzc347/4/

Comment: Now its working but after mousedown if you will drag it left then capturing is not working properly.

Comment: yeah even i noticed that..when its done slowly it works.

Comment: some link drag or image drag is happening when you drag it left...due to that mousup event is not working.

Comment: link drag and image drag happens Only if u don't add jquery

Comment: So, better you add jquery inside <head></head>

Comment: no i don't want to use jQuery..i'm making it for all devices and all browsers...draging issue is coming only with chrome and safari.

Answer (score 0):

Its not supported in Chrome see https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-bugs/NZvlBWQ3L3A

Comment: is there any alternative to do it in chrome?

Comment: I'm sure there is but Im a bit confused what .setCapture is actually used for?

Comment: see this [link] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setCapture)

Answer (score 0):

No need to call setCapture() method in chrome browser, only required for mozilla browser.

Use e.target.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoved, true); in chrome

```
function mouseMoved(e) {
var output = document.getElementById("output");
console.log("Position: " + e.clientX + ", " + e.clientY);
}
```

@Anoop B.K, His solution will work fine, because he is checking condition in mouseDown Event method whether "e.target.addEventListener" or e.target.setCapture is true.

Comment: Please go through this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setCapture